# Entity Framework Migration: Why does it ignore snapshot and take __MigrationHistory into account?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 6.0.0 and .Net 4.5.

I face a very confusing problem. Me and one of my colleagues are working on the domain model section of our project on two different clients. The problem is:

**1-** Me and my colleagues start with the absolutely identical project and we are completely synced with the source control.

**2-** When I change the model for example add a property then `Add-Migration FromA` then `Update-Database` it works great. The generated code file contains just one command that is to add the column.

**3-** Meanwhile, after the `db` is updated and just before I check in something to source control, my colleague adds another property and then `Add-Migration FromA` then `Update-Database`. And guess what? This generated code file **has a command to drop the column I newly added!!!**

I added another column using native Sql, and fortunately the column is not going to be deleted.

I deleted the `__MigrationHistory` table and the remove column didn't get generated.

I turned off initializer `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null)`, no success.

So, my guess is that `EF Migrations` compares current model with the last one stored in `__MigrationHistory` table not the last local snapshot stored in `.resx` file. Am I right? Any way to solve the problem?

Comment: check this out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx

Comment: @dotctor This is completely different. The difference is that I don't check in anything. The only changes visible to other clients are in DB not source control

Comment: are you sharing a single instance of database?

Comment: you shouldn't, It's like you both edit a same source file at a same time. use local instances of db and do not share them and do the merging process described in that article when merging conflicts happen

Comment: Look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13314725/861716

Comment: @dotctor  thanks a lot. I missed the point that every developer should work on local db to compare himself to his own previous works.

Comment: @dotctor But why does EF even take __MigrationHistory table into account? I expected it compares current model with the last snapshot stored in resource file. If it had done the job like this, this problem wouldn't have occurred. If current model is always get compared with __MigrationHistory  what is the point of snapshot?

Comment: I don't know, that is the EF team design decision.

Comment: Yep, if you read that whole msdn article like it says you should, you'll walk away with the wrong impression.  The migrations that get generated definitely depend (also) upon what's in the database - not just what's in the previous resx file.