# Entity framework code first - best practice for migrations on multiple environments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, production-environment, entity-framework-migrations

Our team works on a website with ASP MVC5 & EF5. there are 3 machines involved in my question:

1. Developer's machine
2. Test server
3. Production server

So a regular work cycle is: the developer adding features & puts them on the test server when there are some approved tested features they goes to the Production server.
 When there are no model changes - everything works great.
But, when there are model changes - sometimes the migration gets wrong.
and the DB get so messed up so we need to backit up, clear everything & copy the data from the backup.
what we do is:

1. Add migration on dev-env.
2. Copy all the source to the test/production (Model & Migration folders).
3. Update database.

when doing this basic cycle some times the migration failes to update because of table already exists; I guess im doing something wrong in the process.

Another bad thing:
we have copy of the development environment on the Test & Production servers - my guess is that we dont need VS on the server in order to update version (we use the VS to run the EF commands from the package manager.

**My question is**

Is there any best practice/manual regarding dev->test->production process & how to do it right with code first & no visual studio on the servers?

Comment: Migrations also can be automatically executed on the application start. If you use MigrateToLatest db initializer and have disabled AutomaticMigrations, then during startup if DB is different then model - EF will execute pending migrations, and if they are the same - will continue to working. Or just fail with exception if some migration is missing

Comment: thanks @SergeyLitvinov Can you explain in more detailed manner how it can be done? do you have any good referance regarding that issue?

Comment: I wouldn't run migrations against PROD. You can create scripts that will conditionally test for what has been applied (idempotent). See this http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Comment: Here is the idempotent part. Basically you get a long script that checks if each migration has been run on TEST or PROD and executes the ones that have note and update the __MigrationHistory table. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#idempotent

Comment: Here's one on working in a team environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314725/migrations-in-entity-framework-in-a-collaborative-environment

Comment: Use migrate.exe to run migrations on your build server without VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

Comment: Thanks @SteveGreene, In general, do I need automaticMigration set to enabled or Disabled?

Comment: See "Avoid automatic migrations" here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx